# Collapsable sidenav

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu, sidenav

I've created a two column layout with a sidenav on the left for links to other pages, and made it responsive so that everything stacks on small screens. My client isn't happy with the look on small screens and wants the side nav to collapse to an icon or toggle button on small screens.

I'm not using a framework at all and I'm hoping to create the same effect as this 
[Bootstrap sidenav](https://www.bootply.com/94838). Is there a way to do this without a framework?

Comment: Are you after a hamburger-menu icon in small width screen, for the sidenav?

Comment: First result on google when searching 'pure css hamburger menu':
https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP
Maybe this helps

Comment: Another off canvas example https://codepen.io/hyyan/pen/LdoVjN

Comment: Yes I want the nav always on screen on desktop screens and then collapsing to a hamburger or similar on small screens which can then be displayed by the user. Thanks for the link I'll take a look at that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what you're after. A full width **Navbar** in large / medium desktop resolution and a **Hamburger** menu in small resolution.

```js
$("nav").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background: #3498db;
}


/* Flex Nav Bar */

.flex-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.flex-nav li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.flex-nav li:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
}

.flex-nav li:hover {
  background: #2980b9;
  flex: 1.1;
}

.flex-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Hamburger Icon */

nav .hamburger {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav .hamburger i,
nav .hamburger i:before,
nav .hamburger i:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

nav .hamburger i {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  left: 6px;
}

nav .hamburger i:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
}

nav .hamburger i:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}

nav.active .hamburger {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

nav.active .hamburger i {
  background: transparent;
}

nav.active .hamburger i:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav.active .hamburger i:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-nav li {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    color: transparent;
  }
  .flex-nav>li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: none;
  }
  nav .hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav.active .flex-nav li {
    display: block;
    height: initial;
    color: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="hamburger"><i></i></div>
    <ul class="flex-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this worked. just needed to fiddle it for my vertical nav but works exactly the way I wanted.